# how to make the file upload selection block

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I currently want the user to upload a file for some processing.

So, I have a form element as follows:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="post" onSubmit="return submitDocument()">
    <button class="ui left floated positive submit button" id="upload-button" type="submit">Upload Document</button>
</form>
```

There is a corresponding file input object as:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)" class="inputfile" id="embedfileinput" accept="image/*, application/pdf, application/msword" style="display:none"/>
```

and then I have the javascript as:

```
function showProcessing() {
     $('#processing').dimmer('show');
     return true;
}

function submitDocument() {
    document.getElementById('embedfileinput').click();
    showProcessing();
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that as soon as I click the upload button, the form gets submitted. What I would like to do is trigger the submission task after the file has been selected.

Is there a way to make this file selection blocking?

Comment: document.getElementById('embedfileinput').click(); use change instead of click'

Comment: you have your `input file` element hidden by `display: none` so I'm not sure how you are actually loading the file before submitting the form. The click action on the submit button of course submits the form. So if you are controlling the event of the input file on change, you maybe should make it visible and wire those actions to its change event? if you want also to prevent submitting the form if no file was loaded yet, you should have a condition on your submit event that will do `event.preventDefault()` avoiding the form submission

Comment: @Nisha That does not show my file dialog, of course and still submits the form.

Comment: @DiegoD I hide it as I want the file dialog to show on the button click. I am sure this has been done before i.e. submit the form after the file has been chosen.

Comment: @Luca - Is there any particular reason to show the file-dialog as part of the submit process? I ask, because your method seems convoluted. I would instead make form submission a part of the onchange event when a 'valid file chosen' flag is true. I.e, show the dialog when a button is pressed. When you get the change event, check to see that the user did actually select a file (rather than hit cancel) then do a `form.submit()`.

Comment: hmmmmm that makes more sense. I am just inexperienced with it, so this is what I cobbled together...Maybe I will not trigger the submit on button click but as part of the file change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. As soon as you click the submit button and the button is inside the form tag, your form is gonna be submitted. That's default behavior. To prevent it, put a `onclick="clickListener(event)"` in your button and call `event.preventDefault()` to avoid this behaviour. Second, doing so will NOT trigger a `onsubmit` event in you form. So there's no sense having such attribute in the form. Try this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="post">
    <button class="ui left floated positive submit button" id="upload-button" type="submit" onclick="clickListener(event)">Upload Document</button>
</form>
```

in your javascript:

```
function clickListener(e) {
    // call your custom code here
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Note that I removed onsubmit attibute from the form tag.

You can always call form.submit() to submit manually.
More details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit